# add product to cart with product options

Tags: api, product-attribute, soap, shopping-cart, custom-options

i try to add product to cart wih this code :

```
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); 
    try{
    $result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionID, $cartID, array(array(
    'product_id' => $productID,
    'sku' => $sku,
    'qty' => $qty,
    'options' => null,
    'bundle_option' => null,
    'bundle_option_qty' => null,
    'links' => null
    )));  

    } catch(SoapFault $e){

       $result = $e->getMessage();
       }
```

i found it from this link : [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html)

on link example it`s pass null for options if i want to add options like color or size or ... to product and then add the prodoct to cart what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html) from your link above, the shoppingCartProductEntity array attribute "options" is an **associativeArray** in the form of `option_id => content`.

I found a nice answer on stackoverflow "[Setting Custom Options while adding a product to cart via SOAP in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899127/setting-custom-options-while-adding-a-product-to-cart-via-soap-in-magento/)" regarding this problem and the declaration as provided in the documentation does not seem correct.

The right way seems to be:

```
'options' => 
        array(
          0 => 
            array(
              'key' => 1
              'value' => 2),
          1 => 
            array(
              'key' => 3
              'value' => 4),              
        )
```

Comment: is 'key'  title of option ? and 'value' value of option ? like Color , Red  ?